# Who were the people in Asuna's flashback in episode 18?

Tags: sword-art-online

In the episode 18 of SAO II, there was a flashback of Asuna's trip to Kyoto. In it, she's seen talking to some guys. She declines that this is an arranged marriage, but there was no mention of who they were or what it was about.

Who were these people? Is this going to be significant to the story in any way?

Please remember to use spoiler tags when necessary.

Comment: It looked like they were harassing Asuna on the trip to me, she just said she remembered something bad.

Comment: That's the idea I was getting, but but SAO doesn't seem like the kind of anime that would put in unnecessary details like that unless it was part of the story somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible spoilers for future episodes:

> Well, in the light novel, Asuna's mum keeps on trying to arrange her a marriage (yes, even after the Sugou incident) to a rich guy, and not someone like Kazuto. She wants Asuna to be the high class girl she was born as, and to stay that way.
>
>  So those were probably the random rich guys her mum wanted to introduce, there was also a scene where she was talking at a table... that might have been her cousin that her mum also tried setting her up with.
>
>  But it's alright, Asuna ends up showing her mum her log cabin on ALO, and it happens to look like the home her mum had lived in as a child (as the mum was born to a middle class family), blah blah blah, emotional moment, Asuna's mum relents and tells Asuna to try her hardest to get the person she loves, and she readily agrees.
>
>  And Asuna x Kirito fans lived happily ever after.